# JBoss CLI: add a nested element within an element without name attribute (adding "key" element inside "jwt")

Tags: jboss, jwt, command-line-interface, jboss-cli, elytron

Generally speaking, I am trying to add a nested element inside another one, where the parent element does not contain a `name` attribute:

```
<parentElement name="fooName">
    <foo property1="abc"/>
</parentElement>
```

should become:

```
<parentElement name="fooName">
    <foo property1="abc">
        <fooChild property2="bcd"/>
    </foo>
</parent>
```

The problem with this is that I cannot find a way to properly build the path for the `CLI` command:

```
/sybsystem=xxx/parentElement=fooName/foo:add(fooChild={property2="bcd"})
```

gives me an error `Node path format is wrong around 'foo' (index=37).`

I assume this is because the `foo` element doesn't have an attribute `name`.

---

More specifically I am looking for a way to add `key` element inside the `jwt` element:

```
         <token-realm name="jwt-realm" principal-claim="sub">
                <jwt issuer="${JWT_ISSUER}" audience="${JWT_AUDIENCE}" public-key="${JWT_PUBLIC_KEY}"/>
         </token-realm>
```

should become:

```
           <token-realm name="jwt-realm" principal-claim="sub">
                <jwt issuer="${JWT_ISSUER}" audience="${JWT_AUDIENCE}" public-key="${JWT_PUBLIC_KEY}">
                    <key kid="xxx" public-key="${JWT_PUBLIC_KEY}"/>
                </jwt>
           </token-realm>
```

The command I am trying to use:

```
/subsystem=elytron/token-realm=jwt-realm/jwt:add(key={kid="xxx",public-key="${JWT_PUBLIC_KEY}"})
```

and the error I get: `Node path format is wrong around 'jwt' (index=41).`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my outstanding colleague (he hasn't got an account here, shame), the answer has been found.

To update the `key`'s map the following command can be used:

```
/subsystem=elytron/token-realm=jwt-realm:write-attribute(name=jwt, ... ,key-map={"xxx","${JWT_PUBLIC_KEY}"}})
```

(`...` here the list of other standard attributes of the `jwt` element).

Answer (score 0):

For me this did it (whereas the suggested solution didn't), I am using WildFly 31:

```bash
/subsystem=elytron/token-realm=jwt-realm:add(jwt={issuer=["quickstart-jwt-issuer"], audience=["jwt-audience"], key-map={1="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MII...AAE=-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"}}, principal-claim="sub")
```

This created this element in the `standalone.xml` file:

```xml
<token-realm name="jwt-realm" principal-claim="sub">
    <jwt issuer="quickstart-jwt-issuer" audience="jwt-audience">
        <key kid="1" public-key="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MII...AAE=-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"/>
    </jwt>
</token-realm>
```

Hope this helps.